# Angular How to inject post data into a html view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-formly

I am using node.js and Angular 1.3x Usually I serve up the first page like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('layouts/my.html', { root: __dirname })
})
```

and from my.html I access post data like so:

```
app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts) {
    if(err) { return next(err)}
    res.json(posts)
  })
})
```

How do I combine both of the above things? In other words, I want to call a URL from a non-web application, pass in post data, set angular model to incoming post data and display resulting html page.

Comment: may be choose web socket implementation..

Comment: You will have to create a page with Angular.js included and call this API from that page. Read at https://angularjs.org/ : Topic: "Wire up a Backend"

Comment: I don't understand. You want to call the API from a software (non-web), and the result of the post should be loaded in an angular application? Then yes, you might want to take a look at websockets (socket.io)

Comment: The scenario is, I want to inject Angulary-Formly field definitions into the page that is initially loaded. Query parameters parsing would probably be insufficent (lot of data) for this.

Comment: The other thoughts I had were to persist the form field json definitions to db first then angular which is called with a unique ID parm can use it to call a node api to retrieve it. Or <shudder> instead of db simply have node get and post methods to set and retrieve a variable obj = {key, value} in node server itself, after all its temporary.